# Ruby on Rails - Adding counter_cache to my table with using punching_bag gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Im using `punching_bag` for counting `hits` to my posts. Everything works fine but I want to add `counter_cache` to my `posts` table for `punches/hits` for better performance and some other functions I want to add using that.

Is it possible to do what I am looking for?

*What I am using:*

`Rails 4.2.4`

[`punching_bag` gem](https://github.com/biola/punching_bag)

Comment: From lookking at the gem's documentation seems like that's not supported. you'll need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Let say you want to add `counter_cache` to `posts` table*

First make a migration to add `punches_count` column to `posts` table:

```
class AddPunchesCountToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :punches_count, :integer, default: 0
    Post.find_each { |post| Post.reset_counters(post.id, :punches) }
  end
end
```

*NB:* `Post.find_each { |post| Post.reset_counters(post.id, :punches) }` add all existing punches to each post.

- **Run migration**
- Search for `punch.rb` in your gem file & add `:counter_cache => true` to `belongs_to :punchable`. Line would then be:

`belongs_to :punchable, :polymorphic => true, :counter_cache => true`